# Process freeze when using multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm developing an application to create a datalist. the actual data are expected to be a large size data, which is why I try to separate python process on a multiple process by using multiprocessing library. but when I try to call on my method by using multiprocess, the process itself stop without showing any error.

I'm using python 3.6 on my environment, and I already try using itertools and functool's partial to make sure my parameter are being send correctly. but for now nothing works.

import sys
   import os
   import numpy as np
   import flask
   import matplotlib
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
   import matplotlib.dates as mdates
   import pandas as pd
   from io import BytesIO
   from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
   from matplotlib.dates import date2num
   import datetime
   import calendar
   import multiprocessing
   from functools import partial
   from contextlib import contextmanager
   from itertools import product

```
def count_defect_by_defName_and_part(dataFrame,target,target2,row,defectName,partName,tempCount):
    count = pd.pivot_table(dataFrame,columns=[target,target2],index=row["groupName"],values=row["itemName"],aggfunc="count",dropna=False)[defectName][partName]
    count = pd.DataFrame(count)
    count["subGroup"]=count.index
    count["groupName"]=row["groupName"]
    count.rename(columns={partName:"count"}, inplace=True)
    tempCount.append(count)
    return tempCount

#parameter for testing
filterParam=pd.DataFrame(columns=["filterName","param1","param2"])
filterParam = filterParam.append({"filterName":"成形日","param1":"2018-12-28","param2":"2019-02-12"},ignore_index=True)

    dataFrame = csv_file
    groupList = ["型番区分","一分値区分","比重区分","揺変性区分","流れ区分","泥温区分","比重区分","肉厚区分","珪曹添加量区分"]
    defectName = "ｷﾚ"
    partName = "トラップ"
    target = "欠点"
    target2 = "部位名称"

    #データ区分マスターから情報を取得
    dataGroup = pd.read_csv('../../Dataframe_Creator/config/data_group_master.csv',encoding="ms932")

    countList = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(groupList,columns=["groupName"]),dataGroup, on=["groupName"], how="left", indicator="exist")
    rankingList=pd.DataFrame(columns=["groupName","min","max","rift"])
    loopFrame = countList.drop_duplicates(subset=["groupName"])
    tempCount = []
```

## code with the problem

```
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1) as pool:
        results = pool.map(partial(count_defect_by_defName_and_part, dataFrame=dataFrame,target=target,target2=target2,
                                   defectName=defectName,partName=partName,tempCount=tempCount), product(loopFrame, repeat=2))   
        pool.close() # no more tasks
        pool.join()  # wrap up current tasks
```

when I try to run the process directly without multiprocessing it running just fine and the process finished in about 5 minutes.